# Magento 2: Removing Layered Navigation stops filters working

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, attributes, layered-navigation

I am developing a custom theme which does not display the layered navigation filters, so I edited my **catalog_category_view.xml** adding the instruction:

```
<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" remove="true" />
```

Removing the filters stops the layered navigation to work properly. If I visit the URL **http://myurl.com/category-url-key?attribute_code=10** the site shows every product belonging to **category-url-code**, ignoring the filter **attribute_code=10**.

How do I make the layered navigation work without showing the layered navigation filters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **'display'** instead. So use :

`<referenceBlock name="catalog.leftnav" display="false" />`

**Reference :**

[Dev Docs XML](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-instructions.html)

**Display Explanation :**

> Allows you to disable rendering of specific block or container with
>   all its children (both set directly and by reference). The
>   block's/container's and its children' respective PHP objects are still
>   generated and available for manipulation.